# how to get HashTable values as Arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashtable

Hashtable  hw

How can I convert its values to:

```
ArrayList <Word> arr
```

thanks.

Comment: I find this rather amusing :)

Comment: This always happens on easy questions. Personally I think it's classy to delete a duplicate answer you posted if it doesn't contribute anything more than an answer that was submitted before you, but people actually doing that is exceedingly rare

Comment: @Michael, For me it is fun to race to be the first to answer, while still providing the best content.

Comment: @Justin Me too, but if you lose the race there's no point leaving your answer around unless it provides extra information the others don't. There are verbatim answers posted on this one -- that adds nothing of value

Comment: @Michael I agree.  But if I get an upvote or two, I'd like to keep that reputation around.  I don't think it ads clutter (too much) if they are all correct.

Comment: @Justin Sure; that's why I called it classy, it's nice to see people willing to lose 10 or 20 rep to clean up a question somewhat (although I think the rep stays around until a recalc). I don't expect it to happen often though, and you're right, it's not a big deal

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Use the `ArrayList` constructor that takes a collection.

```
ArrayList<Word> arr = new ArrayList<Word>(hw.values());
```

Then every value that was in the `HashTable` will be in the new `ArrayList`.

You can find documentation about the constructor in [the javadocs](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 10):

```
ArrayList<Word> arr = new ArrayList<Word>( hw.values() );
```

Answer (score 9):

Also you can use

```
ArrayList<Word> arr = Collections.list(hw.keys());
```

for keys as ArrayList

Comment: keys wanted thx! any idea why they return keys as enumeration and not collection?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
hw.values();
```

it will simply return the Collection (like a List) of `Word` objects.

---

from javadocs

**values**

public Collection **values()**

> Returns a Collection view of the
>   values contained in this map. The
>   collection is backed by the map, so
>   changes to the map are reflected in
>   the collection, and vice-versa. If the
>   map is modified while an iteration
>   over the collection is in progress
>   (except through the iterator's own
>   remove operation), the results of the
>   iteration are undefined. The
>   collection supports element removal,
>   which removes the corresponding
>   mapping from the map, via the
>   Iterator.remove, Collection.remove,
>   removeAll, retainAll and clear
>   operations. It does not support the
>   add or addAll operations.